# How can I find members of my email list on Twitter?

Tags: twitter, email, import

I run an email newsletter and I'd like to see which of the people on the list are on Twitter.

I've tried [this method](https://www.taiwebdesign.co.uk/how-to-find-twitter-handles-from-your-email-list/) of importing the contacts to a Gmail account, creating a Twitter account with that email, then allowing Twitter to access my address book. But the "Manage contacts" page on Twitter is blank for me, similar to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Twitter/comments/kaoy8a/how_to_findfollow_contacts_on_twitter/).

Is there another way of doing this?